# How to horizontally align a plotly chart?

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash

I have a plot in my dash app that contains a graph which I cannot figure out how to horizontally align. The only way I can get the graph to become horizontally aligned is when I remove the `python width=400` parameter from the graph, but then the graph becomes larger than I would like it to be. How can I have my graph be horizontally aligned just as the buttons are horizontally aligned in my code below, while still being able to manipulate its height?

```py
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output, State
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import plotly.io as pio
from nba_api.stats.static import players
from nba_api.stats.endpoints.shotchartdetail import ShotChartDetail
import datetime

pio.templates.default= "none"

court_shapes = []

outer_lines_shape = dict(
    type='rect',
    xref='x',
    yref='y',
    x0='-250',
    y0='-47.5',
    x1='250',
    y1='422.5',
    line=dict(
        color='rgba(10, 10, 10, 1)',
        width=1
    )
)

court_shapes.append(outer_lines_shape)

hoop_shape = dict(
    type='circle',
    xref='x',
    yref='y',
    x0='7.5',
    y0='7.5',
    x1='-7.5',
    y1='-7.5',
    line=dict(
        color='rgba(10, 10, 10, 1)',
        width=1
    )
)

court_shapes.append(hoop_shape)

backboard_shape = dict(
    type='rect',
    xref='x',
    yref='y',
    x0='-30',
    y0='-7.5',
    x1='30',
    y1='-6.5',
    line=dict(
        color='rgba(10, 10, 10, 1)',
        width=1
    ),
    fillcolor='rgba(10, 10, 10, 1)'
)

court_shapes.append(backboard_shape)

outer_three_sec_shape = dict(
    type='rect',
    xref='x',
    yref='y',
    x0='-80',
    y0='-47.5',
    x1='80',
    y1='143.5',
    line=dict(
        color='rgba(10, 10, 10, 1)',
        width=1
    )
)

court_shapes.append(outer_three_sec_shape)

inner_three_sec_shape = dict(
    type='rect',
    xref='x',
    yref='y',
    x0='-60',
    y0='-47.5',
    x1='60',
    y1='143.5',
    line=dict(
        color='rgba(10, 10, 10, 1)',
        width=1
    )
)

court_shapes.append(inner_three_sec_shape)

left_line_shape = dict(
    type='line',
    xref='x',
    yref='y',
    x0='-220',
    y0='-47.5',
    x1='-220',
    y1='92.5',
    line=dict(
        color='rgba(10, 10, 10, 1)',
        width=1
    )
)

court_shapes.append(left_line_shape)

right_line_shape = dict(
    type='line',
    xref='x',
    yref='y',
    x0='220',
    y0='-47.5',
    x1='220',
    y1='92.5',
    line=dict(
        color='rgba(10, 10, 10, 1)',
        width=1
    )
)   

court_shapes.append(right_line_shape)

three_point_arc_shape = dict(
    type='path',
    xref='x',
    yref='y',
    path='M -220 92.5 C -70 300, 70 300, 220 92.5',
    line=dict(
        color='rgba(10, 10, 10, 1)',
        width=1
    )
)

court_shapes.append(three_point_arc_shape)

center_circle_shape = dict(
    type='circle',
    xref='x',
    yref='y',
    x0='60',
    y0='482.5',
    x1='-60',
    y1='362.5',
    line=dict(
        color='rgba(10, 10, 10, 1)',
        width=1
    )
)

court_shapes.append(center_circle_shape)

res_circle_shape = dict(
    type='circle',
    xref='x',
    yref='y',
    x0='20',
    y0='442.5',
    x1='-20',
    y1='402.5',
    line=dict(
        color='rgba(10, 10, 10, 1)',
        width=1
    )
)

court_shapes.append(res_circle_shape)

free_throw_circle_shape = dict(
    type='circle',
    xref='x',
    yref='y',
    x0='60',
    y0='200',
    x1='-60',
    y1='80',
    line=dict(
        color='rgba(10, 10, 10, 1)',
        width=1
    )
)

court_shapes.append(free_throw_circle_shape)

res_area_shape = dict(
    type='circle',
    xref='x',
    yref='y',
    x0='40',
    y0='40',
    x1='-40',
    y1='-40',
    line=dict(
        color='rgba(10, 10, 10, 1)',
        width=1,
        dash='dot'
    )
)

court_shapes.append(res_area_shape)

external_stylesheets = ['https://codepen.io/chriddyp/pen/bWLwgP.css']

app = dash.Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets=external_stylesheets)

colors = {
    'background': '#111111',
    'text': '#7FDBFF'
}

app.layout = html.Div([
    html.Div([
        dcc.Graph(
            id='shot-graph',
            figure={
                'layout': go.Layout( 
                    title="test",
                    shapes= court_shapes,
                    height=400,
                    width=400,
                    xaxis= dict(
                        showgrid=False,
                        range=[-300, 300],
                        showticklabels=False,
                        zeroline=False
                    ),
                    yaxis= dict(
                        showgrid=False,
                        range=[-100, 500],
                        showticklabels=False,
                        zeroline=False
                    )
                )
            },
            config={
                'displayModeBar': False,
                'staticPlot': True
            }
        ),
    ]),
    html.Div([
            dcc.Input(id='playerName-state', type='text', value='Brook Lopez'),
            dcc.Input(id='season-state', type='text', value='2018-19'),
            html.Button('Submit', id='button')
    ],style = {"width": "100%", "display": "flex", "align-items": "center", "justify-content": "center"})
])

@app.callback(
    Output('playerName-state', 'value'),
    [Input('button', 'n_clicks')]
)
def update_figure(n_clicks):
    return n_clicks

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

Comment: See if you can find a CSS class of a div that wraps your chart and do something there - either with some flexbox property or with `margin: 0 auto;'